# Reading large json.gz file in python getting MemoryError

Tags: python, json, gzip

I have large dataset stored in a json.gz file. Around 1.4GB in size. But when i use my code that i used to load in smaller json.gz files I get a `MemoryError`. So what can i use to load in a larger json.gz file, or can i split it in smaller sizes without needing to load in the whole file?

Code:

```
import gzip
def parse(path):
    g = gzip.open(path, 'r')
    for l in g:
        yield eval(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop with `g.read(size)`, where is size is some reasonable number of uncompressed bytes to process at a time. When you get no bytes back, you have reached the end of the input, and you exit the loop.